# gtihub site does not add some images

Tags: html, css, github, visual-studio-code, github-pages

I having this bug where two of the images used on my website don't show up on the github version but do in the local one and the images are in github as well in the same place that other images work from. Here is the link to the website and the link to the github source code. [website on github](https://bobjoerules.github.io/DarkMode-sheet/)[source code](https://github.com/bobjoerules/DarkMode-sheet)

[image: google inspect sources shows no image]

[image: code shows link to image file]

[image: github version]

[image: local version]

Comment: which image specifically are you talking about? Are you sure this isn't just a case of you needing to wait? Or having to update the commit that your gh-pages branch is tracking?

Comment: Do you have anything in a git ignore file?

Comment: @RiverTam nope nothing is in there

Comment: @user the search image and the logo. (Showed example of search image) I have waited along time and other images are updating but those two aren’t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [`images/Bobjoerules.png`](https://github.com/bobjoerules/DarkMode-sheet/blob/master/images/Bobjoerules.png), try and reference it with a relative path:

```
<div class="col"><img src="images/Bobjoerules.png" class="logo"...
                          ^^^ (no /)
```

It is the only 404 reported by the [browser developer console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/).

Comment: I also get 404 for their `images/search.png`

Comment: I do not see a 404 reported by the developer tool console though.

Comment: Oh I guess locally / in front works but it doesn’t in GitHub thanks